# Excel Add-in called by ActiveX javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, excel, activex, sapui5

I am developing a SAPUI5 application which needs to communicate with Excel and start an Excel add-in which get the data from UI5.
The add-in worked before with SQL but it was also called with an ActiveX element by VB from Access. I can start Excel and send the data to it but can't find information how to call an add-in. Now I need to know how can I start the add-in with my ActiveX object from Javascript.

Comment: Are you using an ActiveX component embedded in your UI5 application to talk to Excel?

Comment: @jpenninkhof Yes here is my Code to start excel from my UI5  
application with the ActiveX component:  
var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");   
var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add();  
var oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;  
oSheet.Name = "CEM Bericht"; 
oXL.Visible = true;  
and too before i set it visible i fill the sheet but these are too many  characters and sry for formattings i they won't work first try.

Comment: That sounds more like a .Net thing than a UI5 thing to be honest. You seem to have managed to get communication between the JS environment and the ActiveX control going already, but are stuck at calling the add-in. You have tagged your question with Excel and ActiveX. Perhaps is would be good to tag it with `.Net` as well. Hopefully someone from the .Net community will be able to help you further.

Comment: ok thanks for that information I will add the tag directly.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry that I can't help you further. But ask me anything UI5 ;)